# hotmail marking valid emails as junk

Tags: email, spam, hotmail

I'm sending notification emails to customers who explicitly ask for this information, but most of the messages are being marked as junk. In some cases the same email with the same content is marked as junk for a user and not marked for another user.

I've tried using different accounts names for the sender, like mi_name@my_enterprise, or your_news@my_enterprise or random_123@my_enterprise with the same erratic behavior; in same case it works, in other it doesn't. I've changed the content too (adding or deleting images, external links, etc) but it didn't work either.

Does anyone have experience with similar problems and can you please help me come up with a solution? Thanks